# Compare rows with each other and keep only one row according to a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement as per below:

If more than 1 comment exist (group of name, lastname, door, amount) and one of them includes `NULL` then keep only the record with the `NULL` comment and discard the others.

If `NULL` is not one of them and the comment includes `NOT AVAILABLE` and `REQUIRES`. Keep `NOT AVAILABLE` - discard `REQUIRES`.

```
Name    Lastname   Comment                    Amount    Door
------------------------------------------------------------
John    R.         NULL                          250    1
John    R.         NULL                          250    1
John    R.         New design is available       250    1
John    R.         Not available                 250    2
John    R.         Requires additional comment   250    2
John    R.         XYZ                           200    3
John    R.         Requires more information     200    4
John    R.         Requires more information     200    4
John    R.         Requires more information     200    4
John    R.         ABC                           200    4
```

Result should look like:

```
Name    Lastname   Comment                    Amount    Door
-------------------------------------------------------------
John    R.         NULL                          250    1
John    R.         Not available                 250    2
John    R.         XYZ                           200    3
John    R.         Requires more information     200    4
John    R.         Requires more information     200    4
John    R.         Requires more information     200    4
John    R.         ABC                           200    4
```

It should only check for those rows which have comment for more than 1. Problem statement is such that it should check for `NULL` comment and not available comments and discard the others but if in case these two are not present then data should go as it is.

I am trying to write a CTE to get the result but not sure how to compare the comment section. Something like below

```
WITH RNs AS
(
    SELECT 
        name,
        lastname,
        door,
        package,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name,lastname, comment, amount, door 
                           ORDER BY name, lastname, amount, door ASC) AS RN
    FROM 
        test
)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is an exact duplicate of your earlier question and you have not accepted an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone might come up with something a bit more elegant, however this produces the desired output with your sample data.

This partitions by your requirement for the grouping classification to order the rows sequentially per group, and within each group additionally by a second ordering criteria to rank the `not available/requires` comments.

It then creates a sum per group to count the number of `null/not available` occurences per group.

It then selects the first row from each group, or, where there are no multiple occurences of null/not available.

```
with cte as (
    select *, Row_Number() over (
            partition by name, lastname, amount, door
            order by case when comment like 'not available%' then 1 else case when comment like 'requires%' then 2 else 0 end end
        ) rn,
     Sum(case when comment is null or comment like 'not available%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name, lastname, amount, door) gp
    from test
    )
select [Name], Lastname, Comment, Amount, Door
from cte
where rn=1 or gp=0
order by door, comment desc
```

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, noted and edited :)

Comment: Actually seems quite elegant to me :)

Comment: @sTTu thanks for replying. I find it quite elegant too. I have one query let say suppose we have two rows 
REQUIRES SPTBCK AND NOT AVAILABLE WITH 
REQUIRES
there is not available in between ,in this case requires will get row number as 1 and other one as row no 2.I tried changing the order by clause but in that case rows for nulls will also get changed. Can you please help how I can take care of %not available % condition as well.

Comment: Hi its done
with cte as (
    select *, Row_Number() over (
            partition by name, lastname, amount, door
            order by case when comment is NULL then 1 else case when comment like '%not available%' then 2 else 0 end end
        ) rn,
     Sum(case when comment is null or comment like 'not available%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name, lastname, amount, door) gp
    from test
    )
select [Name], Lastname, Comment, Amount, Door
from cte
where rn=1 or gp=0
order by door, comment desc

Answer (score 0):

The following produces your desired result. Its not pretty because its having to detect the 3 different conditions for keeping a row.

- It checks whether a `NULL` comment exists in the table for the same Name/Lastname/Door/Amount and if so discards any other rows.
- It checks whether a `NOT AVAIABLE` exists in the table for the same Name/Lastname/Door/Amount and if so discards any other `REQUIRES` rows.
- Any other rows are left untouched.

```
declare @Test table ([Name] varchar(12), Lastname varchar(12), Comment varchar(128), Amount money, Door int);

insert into @Test ([Name], Lastname, Comment, Amount, Door)
values
('John',    'R.',         NULL,                          250, 1),
('John',    'R.',         NULL,                         250, 1),
('John',    'R.',         'New design is available',       250, 1),
('John',    'R.',         'Not available',                 250, 2),
('John',    'R.',         'Requires additional comment',   250, 2),
('John',    'R.',         'XYZ',                           200, 3),
('John',    'R.',         'Requires more information',     200, 4),
('John',    'R.',         'Requires more information',     200, 4),
('John',    'R.',         'Requires more information',     200, 4),
('John',    'R.',         'ABC',                           200, 4);

WITH RNs AS (
    SELECT 
        [Name]
        , Lastname
        , Door
        , Amount
        , Comment
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], Lastname, Amount, Door 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN Comment IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC) AS RN
        , CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @Test T1
            WHERE T.[Name] = T1.[Name]
            AND T.Lastname = T1.Lastname
            AND T.Door = T1.Door
            AND T.Amount = T1.Amount
            AND T1.Comment IS NULL
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasNull
        , CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @Test T1
            WHERE T.[Name] = T1.[Name]
            AND T.Lastname = T1.Lastname
            AND T.Door = T1.Door
            AND T.Amount = T1.Amount
            AND T1.Comment LIKE '%not available%'
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasNotAvailable
    FROM @Test T
)
SELECT *
FROM Rns
WHERE (HasNull = 1 AND RN = 1)
OR (HasNotAvailable = 1 AND Comment NOT LIKE '%requires%')
OR (HasNull = 0 AND HasNotAvailable = 0)
ORDER BY Door, Comment;
```

Note: If you present your sample data as DDL+DML (as above) its much easier and faster for people to answer.